# В компилятор ничего не выводиться

Tags: c++

Суть вопроса:Как вывести на экран название туроператора, и цену путевки, если название курорта начинается на «Трус», а количество дней более 18. Вот что написано в текстовом файле 1) Название курорта 2)Цена 3)Название туроператора 4)колличество дней

Трустровка:10000 Феерия@24

Лазаревское:20000 Альянс@10

Гострусо:30000 Сиеста@19

Трустоба:5900 Корал@17

Алдер:6780 Веди@20

Трустервазия:25000 Туристическая@20
Мой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <WINDOWS.h>
using namespace std;

struct pytivka
{
    char nazvaniekyrorta[100];
    int cenapytivki[100];
    char nazvanieoperatora[100];
    int colvodnei[100];
}object;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
    ifstream phile("pytivka.txt");
    if (!phile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!";
        return 0;
    }
    pytivka data;
    char buffer[256];
    const char pattern[] = "Трус";
    while (phile.getline(buffer, 256))
    {
        char* token = strtok(buffer, ": @");
        strcpy(data.nazvaniekyrorta, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ": @");
        data.cenapytivki = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ": @");
        strcpy(data.nazvaniekyrorta, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ": @");
        data.colvodnei = atoi(token);

        if (strncmp(data.nazvaniekyrorta, pattern, sizeof(pattern) - 1) == 0 && data.colvodnei > 18 )
        {
            cout << data.nazvanieoperatora << data.cenapytivki;
        }
    }
    phile.close();
}
```

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем? Напишите, что именно вы ожидали увидеть, а что реально наблюдаете

Comment: Вот что должно было вывестись:

Феерия 10000

Туристическая 25000
А у меня в компилятор просто ничего не выводит вот я и задаю вопрос , в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1) В какой кодировке хранится файл исходного кода? 2) В какой кодировке хранится файл с входными данными?

Comment: Как это узнать?

Comment: Так "Тур" или "Трус"?

Comment: Трус , все верно, я никого не собирался этим оскорбить - это такое задание

Comment: @Young я понимаю, но почему вы ожидаете увидеть "Туристическая" если там нет подстроки "Трус"

Comment: Трустервазия начинаеться на Трус, а у меня задание вывести название оператора Туристическая это название оператора

Comment: Понял! А в чем проблема конкретно? Что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Я сам не знаю в чем проблема , когда я начинаю компилировать , у меня должны выводиться  Феерия 10000 Туристическая 25000 , а у меня вообще ничего не выводиться, может что-то в коде не правильно написал я не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Зачем вам массив `int` в структуре? Правильно он вам не нужен, а нужна просто переменная типа `int`
2. `strtok` возвращает подстроку разделенную по переданному в неё разделителю. В вашем случае данные в файле хранятся таким образом:

   `Название курорта:Цена Название туроператора@кол-во дней`

   Чтобы получить название курорта, нужно разделить строку по `:`, чтобы получить цену по   (пробел), для название туроператора по `@` и кол-во дней не важно по какому разделителю.

   Поподробней про `strtok` можете почитать [тут](http://cppstudio.com/post/747/)
3. Там где нужно записать `nazvanieoperatora` вы записываете еще раз `nazvaniekyrorta`.

Вот измененная внутри цикла часть:

```
char* token = strtok(buffer, ":");
strcpy(data.nazvaniekyrorta, token);
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
data.cenapytivki = atoi(token);
token = strtok(NULL, "@");
//Записываете название оператора
strcpy(data.nazvanieoperatora, token);
token = strtok(NULL, "");
data.colvodnei = atoi(token);
```

Comment: Кстати, в рамках условия задачи сразу после `char* token = strtok(buffer, ":");`  можно уже сравнивать `token`  с `"Трус"` и делать `continue`, если не совпадает

Comment: @avp я знаю :) я на вопросы автора уже не первый раз отвечаю, по этому там фиг его знает, может ему еще для чего то нужны будут данные